# Help required in limits

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, limits, polynomials

Can anyone help me evaluate $f(3)$ with $f(x):=\prod_{k=2}^\infty (1+\frac{2}{x^2-(8k-3)x+4k(4k-3)})$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried substituting $x=3$ into the expression?

Comment: You can split the denominator into $(x-4k)(x-4k+3)$ and take log to convert the pie into summation

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Substituting $x=3$ in the given term
$$1+\frac{2}{x^2-(8k-3)x+4k(4k-3)}$$ and factorizing we get $$2\,{\frac { \left( k-1 \right)  \left( 4\,k-5 \right) }{ \left( 4\,k-3
 \right)  \left( 2\,k-3 \right) }}
$$
and the infinite product is given by $$1/4\,{\frac {{\pi}^{3/2}\sqrt {2}}{ \left( \Gamma \left( 3/4 \right) 
 \right) ^{2}}}
$$

Comment: Gamma functions… Nice !